# How is $\tilde H_i(S^n) =0$ for $i \ne n$?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

[image]

---

I understand the proof of Corollary 2.14 and I know how to show $\tilde H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb Z$ from the propositions 2.6 and 2.8.

However, I don't see how to get $\tilde H_i(S^n) =0$ for $i \ne n$.

Comment: It follows by the inductive hypothesis that $\tilde{H}_{i}(S^{n-1})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ when $i= n-1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: How does it follow that $\tilde H_i(S^n) =0$ for $i \ne n$?

Comment: Suppose we know it's true for $S^0$ and let $n > 0$; the induction hypothesis is as above. If $i > 0$  and $i\neq n$ then $\tilde{H}_i(S^n)\cong \tilde{H}_{i-1}(S^{n-1}) \cong 0$ because $i-1 \neq n-1$; if $i=0$ it follows because $S^n$ is connected.